# Getting all item from choosen tag with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have one page where I show image + tags added to image. I want to make tags clickable and when I click on some tag to open all images which has this tag too.

I have 3 tables: `images` for images, `tags` for tags and  `image_tag` for tags assigned to images with columns (`image_id` and `tag_id`). My models are

In Tag model I've added this relation

```
public function byTags() {    
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Image', 'item_tag');  
}
```

I've added also this to my Image model but I'm not sure if I need it

```
public function byTags() {    
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');  
}
```

This is the href link which should load all images

```
<a href="{!! url('byTag/' . $tag->id) !!}"> {!! $tag->tag !!} </a>
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('byTag/{tag_id}', 'ImageController@byTag')->name('bytag');
```

`byTag()` function in the `ImageController`

```
public function byTag($tag_id){

    $images = Tag::with('byTags')->whereId($tag_id)->get();
    return view('bytag', compact('images'));          
}
```

What is happen when I click on the button is that I get the tag on the view `bytag` instead of the images with this tag.

What I miss here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load images using `Image` model and [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$images = Image::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use($tag_id) {
        $q->where('id', $tag_id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm still beginner in Laravel relations and didn't knew about whereHas. Thanks a lot. This works perfectly.